# нажатие на Listview закрывает приложение при попытке обратиться к разметке элемента списка

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня проблема с нажатием в `Listview` после прокрутки.
То есть, если я нажимаю на содержимое, которое было изначально видно, то все ок. Но если я нажимаю прокрутив список (то есть нажимаю на позицию, которая видна не была), то программа вылетает вот с таким текстом в логах:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object reference

Кто сталкивался?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
         @Override 
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) { 
              TextView tp = (TextView)listView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.userid);
              Log.v("mes",tp.getText().toString()); 
         }
});
```

Comment: @DezarEvm, вы зачем-то пытаетесь получить View из ListView. Так не надо. Нужное вам вью уже передано в виде аргумента. Сделайте так: `TextView tp = (TextView)itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.userid);
              Log.v("mes",tp.getText().toString());`. А ещё лучше - повесьте слушатель внутри адаптера. А ещё лучше - перепишите под RecyclerView

Comment: Ты внимательно читай что советует @ЮрийСПб Он как Иисус! всегда помогает правильно:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь получить `View` из `ListView`. Так не надо.
Нужное вам `View`, т.е. разметка элемента списка - уже передано в виде второго аргумента метода `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id)`. Сделайте так:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
         @Override 
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) { 
              TextView tp = (TextView)itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.userid);
              Log.v("mes",tp.getText().toString()); 
         }
});
```

А ещё лучше - повесьте слушатель внутри адаптера. А ещё лучше - перепишите под RecyclerView